# App icon not showing in title bar

Tags: android, xml, icons, label, android-5.0-lollipop

The App icon, definted in the manifest isn't showing in the latest 5.0.1. It looks just fine in the lesser software updates:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/airoperf"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       >
```

Any ideas why this isn't working anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is working just fine. It is simply off by default, per Material Design.

Use `getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` (native action bar) or `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` (`appcompat-v7` action bar) to enable it.

Comment: Do I have to do this in each Activity or is there a global setting?

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer: There may be a way to toggle it on in a custom theme. Otherwise, yes, this would have to be in every activity.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way -

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```